# Scale Matlab Figure's Outer Frame Using matlab2tikz To Exactly 15.5 cm Width

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I would like to scale my Matlab figure to exactly 15.5 cm in my LaTeX document. I am creating the figure like this:

`figure('Name','FigureName','units','centimeters','position',[0 0 15.5 7.75])`

I am exporting the figure using matlab2tikz:

```
cleanfigure
matlab2tikz('/Users/.../Figures/Ergebnisse/CentimetersTest.tikz')
```

I am embedding the .tikz file like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
         \input{Figures/Ergebnisse/CentimetersTest.tikz}
\caption{CentimetersTest}
\label{CentimetersTest}
\end{figure}
```

This gives me a slightly smaller figure around 14 cm in width. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think `pgfplots` currently have any method for setting the total size of the figures.You can have a look at the `tikzscale` package though, perhaps that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- In the preamble of your document, make sure to have:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%% the following commands are needed for some matlab2tikz features
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\newlength\figurewidth
```

- Use the command `matlab2tikz('myfigure.tex','width', '\figurewidth' );` in Matlab to generate your tikzpicture
- In LaTex use

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setlength\figurewidth{15.5cm} %or any other LaTex compatible length
    \input{myfigure.tex}
    \caption{A caption}
    \label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: This is useful, as long as there is no ylabel. Would you happen to know what to do if there is a ylabel and I would like to scale the entire figure size including the ylabel to e.g. 15.5 cm.

Comment: The command I posted sets the figure to the wished width and then the height is preserved from the original aspect ratio. You can use the same procedure to set the height of your figure and change the aspect ratio inside Latex. The ylabel is another subject. Using the Tikzpicture sets the use of the LaTeX font of your document, so you will need to adjust the font size of your Tikzpicture to your liking.

Comment: Is there now way to set the limits for the entire 'outer frame' of a figure to a certain size? It seems to me that this would be something a lot of people would need. Ideally there would be no scaling involved so the labels do habe the exact same size as they are set to.

Comment: Yes, I see the point. I don't know how to scale the "outer frame" to a given size and rescale the content of the frame preserving the original aspect ratio :( . I'm having trouble with a similar enterprise.

Comment: I just got a tip from another user (John Kormylo) to modify the .tex file generated by matlab2tikz. Inside the ```axis``` environment delete the ```scale axis only``` line. Then, try the same procedure I wrote on the answer. Report your results.

Comment: Just a quick FYI: Removing `scale only axis` helps, but it won't be exact. `width=7cm` gives the same axis width as `scale only axis,width=7cm-45pt`, because the width of the labels isn't calculated, `pgfplots` just allocates 45pt of space for them. The total width  will be `7cm-45pt+<the space taken up by the labels>`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue and made a stupid workaround in matlab. I created an empty axis with the desired size around the actual axis where the data is plotted in. This makes matlab2tikz scale the figure as desired.

So first in Matlab:

```
Height=7.75;
Width=15.5;
AxPos=[2,1,Width-2, Height-1]; % if you subtract a bit more than 2cm in x-direction and 1cm in y direction, the ticks are not cut off.
Fig=figure;
Fig.Units='centimeters';
Fig.Position=[2,4,Width,Height]; 
AxEmpty=gca;
AxEmpty.Units='centimeters';
AxEmpty.YColor=[1 1 1];
AxEmpty.XColor=[1 1 1];
AxEmpty.Position=[0 0 Width Height];
set(AxEmpty,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]);
Ax=axes;
Ax.Units='centimeters';
Ax.Position=AxPos;
% Ax.OuterPosition=[0 0 Width Height]; % Use this line instead of the previous one if you don't want to mess around with spacings around the box.
plot([1 2 3],[1 2 3])
```

Then export it with matlab2tikz:

```
matlab2tikz('figurehandle',Fig,'filename', 'myfigure.tex','width','\figurewidth');
```

Then enter it in Tex as suggested in the answer of symduk.
Hope this helps.